# another type missing in TS with JS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-typings

I was digging across similar questions here but could not find the answer that works in my case.

I use JS react component in TS component.

Piece of JS component:

```
export const DateRangePicker = ({
  startDate,
  endDate,
  onDatesChange,
  minDate,
  maxDate,
  error,
  ...props
}) => {
  const [focusedInput, setFocusedInput] = useState(null);
...
};

DateRangePicker.propTypes = {
  startDate: PropTypes.object.isOptional(),
  endDate: PropTypes.object.isOptional(),
  minDate: PropTypes.object.isOptional(),
  maxDate: PropTypes.object.isOptional(),
  onDatesChange: PropTypes.func.isOptional(),
  error: PropTypes.string.isOptional(),
};
```

Piece of TS component that uses JS component:

```
<DateRangePicker 
  startDate={this.props.searchStartDate as any}
  endDate={this.props.searchEndDate as any}
/>
```

But tsc gives me this error:

```
Type '{ startDate: any; endDate: any; }' 
 is missing the following properties from type 
'{ [x: string]: any; startDate: any; endDate: any; onDatesChange: any; minDate: any; maxDate: any; error: any; }': onDatesChange, minDate, maxDate, errorts(2739)
```

I cant get what is the problem?

Comment: Is it an option for you to re-write the Javascript component in Typescript

Comment: In Typescript you can declare a type like this `type X = {[x: string]: any}` type `X` can be any type you want, with any properties and any values. So if you declare `let x: X` you can assign any object to `x`. I have seen this error before and usually happens when you try to programmaticly construct your own type. Then you get errors like type x: string: any is not assignable to type {hello: string}: "world"

Answer (score 1):

Since it is a JavaSCript/JSX file, you can add `// @ts-nocheck` to skip type checking.

However, I would recommend you to fix it by converting it into TypeScript, in order to keep your code base consistent. All you need to do is to add the required types using interfaces or type aliases.